# Best Practise for Posting Password to PHP/MYSQL Server from Flutter?

Tags: php, flutter, password-hash

I'd like passwords to be stored as encrypted/hashed on a Mysql database. But I'm unsure whether the encryption/hashing should take place at Flutter's Android app side or the servers PHP/Mysql side.

Here's the code for sending the HTTP query from within the Flutter app:

```
http://example.com/ps.php?pp="unhashedpassword";
```

Is this too dangerous? Can it be intercepted when sent by a Flutter/Android app? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: it would be better to hash it server side. Also, use nodejs insetad of php and use firebase authentication instead. Its going to make your job much easier. Firebase authentication is free.

Comment: you also should be using a POST request, web server logs will contain all the passwords otherwise

Comment: I've avoided using firebase because apparently Google then own all your data? I'm not keen to be beholden to them.

Comment: Don't ever encrypt passwords. Store a secure hash of the password in your database instead.

Comment: Don't send a password via GET and definitely do not send it using HTTP protocol. Password must be secret which means it should be send it POST request using HTTPS protocol